# Can pilots take multitools on board in Canada?

Tags: commercial-aviation, security, transport-canada

Can pilots in other countries or Canada carry Swiss army knives onboard on commercial flights? Passengers are not allowed to do that in Canada.

Comment: Funny thing is, they often (always?) have an axe in the cockpit.

Comment: is that an international standard for axes to always be available?

Comment: I only found this: "FAA Section 91.513 states: “Each airplane accommodating more than 19 passengers must be equipped with a crash axe."

Comment: In Geneva you can even [buy them as a passenger](https://www.gva.ch/en/Site/Passagers/Shopping/Commerces/Mode-accessoires/victorinox-airgate-shops-geneve) at the airport (after passing security). No problem, as long as the blade is shorter than 6cm.

Comment: In certain regions of Danish and Canadian arctic airspace the crew is required to carry a shotgun in case of polar bear encounter after a forced landing.

Comment: Axe, shotguns...some people take that zombie thing rather serious.

Comment: @pericynthion on a commercial flight or like those passenger planes of four people?

Comment: @Bianfable in Canada less than 6 cm is allowed now even for passengers.

Comment: Either Gerber or SOG, at one time, made a full-sized TSA compliant multi-tool. Good luck trying to get it through security. Probably more hassle than it’s worth. Even with the big red TSA-compliant logo embedded into the metal. Plus, it lacked any cutting tools (of course).

Answer (score -2):

pilots are never allowed to have any kind of weapon on board. when pilots go to work they have to go security just like the passengers.

there has been accidents because of this. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Express_Flight_705#Flight_crew_and_hijacker

its maybe allowed when the total length is smaller then your hand but i`m not sure if this rule applies to pilots.

Comment: Eh....that’s not exactly true.  Some company SOPs do allow a flight crew to be armed, if needed.

Comment: In the US, pilots can participate in the [Federal Flight Deck Officer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Flight_Deck_Officer) program and are allowed to carry weapons on board.

Comment: And by weapons, Bianfable means firearms. Guns, that is. There are companies that even make pilot flight bags in which to carry them.

Comment: When is something a "weapon", and not simply a tool or random object?  I think many pilots carry briefcases/flight bags, yet these can make quite handy improvised weapons.  And then there's that axe in the cockpit :-)